# How to Sum nested values inside hashMap Firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, hashmap, java-stream

I am currently using Firestore and have the following data in a document:

Here is the Document structure.

Firstly, I would like to get these 3 values ie., phonenumb, chapter1 and its values. 
Secondly, I wish to sum the values of chapter1 and store it against each phonenumb.  This will be later used for graph purposes

[image: Document Structure]
I have managed to get these into an outer and inner HashMaps with the following code:

```
CollectionReference chemistry = db.collection("RESULTS").document("Summary").collection("ChemistryVII");
chemistry
        .whereEqualTo("school", "Test School")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                        if (entry.getKey().contains("chapter")) {
                            if (outer.isEmpty() || !outer.containsKey(map.get("phonenumb"))) {
                                Map<String, Object> inner = new HashMap<>();
                                inner.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                                String phonenumb = map.get("phonenumb").toString();
                                outer.put(phonenumb, inner);
                            } else {
                                Map<String, Object> inner = new HashMap<>();
                                inner.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                                String phonenumb = map.get("phonenumb").toString();
                                outer.put(phonenumb, inner);
                            }
                            doSumm();
                            Toast("Document " + outer.values());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

I now wish to sum the values of the inner HashMap with doSumm() but am running into issues.

My attempt at doSumm is as follows.

```
private void doSumm() {
    int counter = outer.size();
    List<Long> chaptersum = new ArrayList<>();
    Toast("Outer Size "+ outer);

    // Map<String, Map<String, Object>> chapterwise = new HashMap<>();
    //Toast("Map Values " + ((Map) outer.get("5100351003")));
    for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Object>> entry : outer.entrySet()) {
        Map<String, Object> inner = entry.getValue();
        int count = inner.size();
        long summ = inner.values().stream().mapToLong(Long::longValue).sum();
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error at Long::longValue :
"Non-static method cannot be referenced from static content"

Also, I am not sure if this is the optimal way to sum the values inside the nested hashmap.

I need the independent values in the next activity which will display them separately in another graph.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: *I am getting an error at Long::longValue;* What's the error? Please also add your database structure and indicate the exact values you want to sum.